# python vs octave random generator

Tags: python, random, numpy, octave

More specifically, numpy:

```
In [24]: a=np.random.RandomState(4)
In [25]: a.rand()
Out[25]: 0.9670298390136767
In [26]: a.get_state()
Out[26]: 
('MT19937',
 array([1248735455, ..., 1532921051], dtype=uint32),
 2,0,0.0)
```

octave:

```
octave:17> rand('state',4)
octave:18> rand()
ans =  0.23605
octave:19> rand('seed',4)
octave:20> rand()
ans =  0.12852
```

Octave claims to perform the same algorithm (Mersenne Twister with a period of 2^{19937-1})

Anybody know why the difference?

Comment: Are you trying to obtain the same **random** numbers?

Comment: Yes, it would be preferable to generate the _same_ (large) set of "random" numbers for debug

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately the MT19937 generator in Octave does not allow you to initialise it using a single 32-bit integer as `np.random.RandomState(4)` does. If you use `rand("seed",4)` this actually switches to an earlier version of the PRNG used previously in Octave, which PRNG is not MT19937 at all, but rather the Fortran `RANDLIB`.

It is possible to get the same numbers in NumPy and Octave, but you have to hack around the random seed generation algorithm in Octave and write your own function to construct the state vector out of the initial 32-bit integer seed. I am not an Octave guru, but with several Internet searches on bit manipulation functions and integer classes in Octave/Matlab I was able to write the following crude script to implement the seeding:

```
function state = mtstate(seed)

state = uint32(zeros(625,1));

state(1) = uint32(seed);
for i=1:623,
   tmp = uint64(1812433253)*uint64(bitxor(state(i),bitshift(state(i),-30)))+i;
   state(i+1) = uint32(bitand(tmp,uint64(intmax('uint32'))));
end
state(625) = 1;
```

Use it like this:

```
octave:9> rand('state',mtstate(4));
octave:10> rand(1,5)
ans =

   0.96703   0.54723   0.97268   0.71482   0.69773
```

Just for comparison with NumPy:

```
>>> a = numpy.random.RandomState(4)
>>> a.rand(5)
array([ 0.96702984,  0.54723225,  0.97268436,  0.71481599,  0.69772882])
```

The numbers (or at least the first five of them) match.

Note that the default random number generator in Python, provided by the `random` module, is also MT19937, but it uses a different seeding algorithm, so `random.seed(4)` produces a completely different state vector and hence the PRN sequence is then different.

Comment: More complex solution than I had expected, and at the same time only 8 lines of code. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [details of the Mersenne Twister algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister), there are lots of parameters that affect the actual numbers produced.  I don't think Python and Octave are trying to produce the same sequence of numbers.

Comment: fair enough. It would be nice to set, or at least get, the default parameters. I am not so optimistic about that happening with octave. Thanks

Comment: A larger question is: why do you want them to produce the same sequence?

Comment: Yes exactly @mmgp. It's a very nice construct to be able to mimic a random sequence but control it during debug to compare results.

Comment: This isn't quite right. I'm virtually certain that the algorithm per se is identical in both cases. Everyone just takes the official code for MT19937 and uses it. What probably differs is how each implementation takes a seed integer and expands that to an initial 624-word state. If you replicated that initial 624-word state, I'm fairly certain that you would get identical numbers coming out. Providing that the [0..1] float normalization step is the same, of course.

Comment: @RobertKern: Indeed, the seed->initial state  mapping is probably the "detail of the algorithm" that is different.

Comment: The seeding routine is fixed in the MT19937 algorithm. The problem here is that Octave does not allow seeding of its MT generator with anything different from the full state vector so one really has to replicate the seeding routine. `rand('seed',x)` switches to a completely different PRNG.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like numpy is returning the raw random integers, whereas octave is normalising them to floats between 0 and 1.0.

Comment: Nope, in the first snippet `a.rand()` returns a `float` (which [*is* normalized between 0 and 1.0](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html#numpy.random.rand)). Those integers you see are part of the internal state of the RNG.