# sync randomized sample selection between R and Python

Tags: python, r, random

Are there off-the-shelf approaches in R and Python that will allow me to generate identical PRNG results?

**Background**:  I am trying to migrate some code from R to Python.  It contains an algorithm that uses `sample` without replacement.

I can validate the migrated code by either (simpler) show that it produces identical results on a small set of inputs or (more complex) show that the results converge given a larger set of inputs.

Let's say I wanted to take the simple route.  Obviously, the following do not produce identical results, because there are different <s>PRNGs and</s> implementations of sampling functions under the hood.

```
# R
set.seed(1)
sample(0:9,3)
# returns vector 2 3 4
```

and:

```
# Python
import random
random.seed(1)
random.sample(range(10),3)
# returns list 2 1 4
```

I could just suck it up and write my own PRNG, which would be educational but would require more programmer time (on non-optimized code).  If it came to that I would probably opt for the more complex validation.

Are there any alternatives to doing so using existing libraries?  I would prefer not to introduce third-party dependencies (like Java API).  Currently leaning toward `rPython` implementation but open to anything.

**update:** This [closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213298/creating-same-random-number-sequence-in-python-numpy-and-r) does not have an accepted answer, and it does not directly address random selection, just generating a random uniform distribution.

Comment: You could always call R code from within Python to get your random values (or python from within R).  It looks like at least one person has developed a package to accomplish the task of syncing the rng between R and Python https://github.com/GjjvdBurg/SyncRNG

Comment: @Dason thanks -- I'll wrap that into an answer (need to return a sample, which looks like to choose n out of x I need to do `shuffle(x)[:n]`) unless you want to write it