# Matching random seed in R for code coming from Python

Tags: python, r, random-seed

I am given some `python` codes which depends on random numbers. This python code use a `random_seed = 300`.

Now I am trying to replicate this `Python` code in `R`. To make sure that the replication is perfect, I need to compare the end results between `R` and `Python`. Given that, the code depends on the random numbers, is there any way to know the equivalent random seed to be used in `R`?

I had a look into [Creating same random number sequence in Python, NumPy and R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213298/creating-same-random-number-sequence-in-python-numpy-and-r), but it appears to be opposite way implementation i.e. from `R` to `Python`.

There is also a `R` library called `reticulate` where I could run python code in R, but could not figure out if I could fetch the R-equivalent random seed using this library

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Many thanks,

Comment: Can you post the Python code?

Comment: Unfortunately I cant as the code is proprietary

Comment: It's not only about having the same seed in python and R but also using the exact same random number generator algorithm. It's very likely that random numbers are generated differently in Python and R.